# how to move to location in graphics mode

Tags: c, bgi

What code do we use to move at a point on the screen in graphics mode(graphics.h)?As in normal we use goto(x,y).

Comment: A meaningful answer depends on the environment rather than the language.

Comment: +homework tag, "forced to use graphics.h by teacher"

Comment: then +graphics tag and a tag to show that it is about the usage of a specific library... but which? (which library, and which tag, I mean both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have a choice in the matter, here are some tutorials on drawing stuff with `graphics.h`:

[Part 1](http://www.mycplus.com/featured-articles/c-language-graphics-library-reference-part-1/)
[Part 2](http://www.mycplus.com/featured-articles/c-language-graphics-library-reference-part-2/)
[Part 3](http://www.mycplus.com/featured-articles/c-language-graphics-library-reference-part-3/)

Answer (score 2):

C, as a language, has no graphics mode.

Comment: but can use libraries, like "graphics.h" (it seems, a header for a known library...), the OP is not aware likely of the difference (not his fault, I may think), nonetheless a better answer than this can be provided when you realize (as it is easily done) that what he needs is to know "graphics.h" API. Virtual -1 (and citing someone else: this is not an answer, it can be a comment instead)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `graphics.h`. It is a very old DOS library from Borland C++ (note that its not C either but C++). Instead pick up some thing like OpenGL or some higher-level library such as SDL.

Comment: Curses to your teacher then. You should not use `graphics.h`.

Comment: I wonder why a lot of programming course make people use stuffs like "conio.h", "graphics.h"... and the final `system("pause");`... brrr